# Bootstrap div exceeds its content on image gallery

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, image-gallery

I'm using bootstrap's grid to make a responsive gallery of images. Nevertheless, I don't know why each div is misplaced to the left, I can't erase its padding or center the image inside its div [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9EbJ.png). I have tried overflow:hidden; and changing paddings and margins.

Due to this error, the whole gallery is not centered and the last image of each row is cropped to the right.

My code

```css
ul.gallery{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

.presumiendo{
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #A59391;
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  color: #A59391;
  font-weight: 250;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.align-icon{
  left: 0px;
}

.images-portfolio {
  border-left: 0px;
  margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  display: inline;
  width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

li .li-image{
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.images-center{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.portfolio{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="portfolio row">
        <div class="images-center containerimg">
          <div class= "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
          <ul class="gallery ">
            <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li class="li-image"> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li>
            </div>
      <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
       <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
         <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
          <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
          <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
          <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
          <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
           <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
            <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
            <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
            <div class= "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-12">
            <li> <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1"> <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1"> </a> </li></div>
            </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: `width:100%` plus `margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px` - do I still need to say _“you do the math”_ …?

Comment: Oh, it's true. Silly me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are not getting the desired result is the wrong html coding. You should check how to code html and css in right way with bootstrap. Try this code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="portfolio row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <a href="portoliof1.html" data-title="Ejemplo 1">
                <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/cMrf9x/poster.jpg" class="images-portfolio img-responsive" alt="ejempli 1">
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.images-portfolio {
    border-left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why can't I place it in a ul?

Comment: You can surely place it in ul but you should code it like this,
<ul class="row">
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></li>
<li class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></li>
</ul>

You should remember, you should not have any other tags immediately after <ul>. Only <li> can go immediately after <ul>.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! You are my lifesaver

Comment: Happy to help...keep coding